# How can fstab direct linux to mount the root directory if /etc/fstab is in the same partition as the the root directory?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

How can fstab direct linux to mount the root directory if /etc/fstab is in the same partition as the the root directory? Does the operating system partition (typically mounted at /boot) have some sort of file that says which partition should be the mounted as the root directory? Does the OS read all the partitions looking for /etc/fstab files before mounting the root directory? What about system with multiple partitions containing different linux OSes (then there would be multiple partitions with /etc/fstab files)?

Comment: Mounting is the way the (running) linux OS links to storage, but pre-boot, the disk can be read, if you know exactly what you are looking for. MBR and GPT partitions both provide either a specific sector address to load or a pointer to the boot software so that it can be executed as part of boot, without mounting the volume in the way you would for the os users would.

Comment: The boot process does not need to read the fstab file from the filesystem to load and execute the initial ram disk and the kernel. The disk locations of those things are incorporated into the bootloader code, in some cases as direct hardware device block addresses.

Comment: On our sister site: [*How is `/etc/fstab` accessed before root is mounted?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107828/108618)

Answer (score 1):

I think @kreemoweet put it succinctly.

The boot process is a series of different steps, each kickstarting another.

In a typical desktop computer, there will be other processes that create the environment before this happens: BIOS, EFI bootloader, initrd/initramfs processes and kernel loading.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I found that fstab is simply NOT used to mount the root directory (at least on my machine which has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using GRUB). Changing the root directory line of fstab had no imapct, the same partition was still mounted as the root directory.

With the guidance of [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/yojcmk/change_which_partition_is_mounted_to_root/) in which an archlinux user tried to move their root directory to another partition and found that fstab had no impact. That archlinux user found that in /boot/grub/grub.cfg there is a direction to mount a certain partition UUID as the root directory.